# Why are additive limit preserving functors left exact?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

I understand that the kernel is a limit and thus preserved by the functor, but why is exactness preserved in the middle?
i.e How does the exactness of $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ imply
the exactness of $0\to F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)$ at $F(B)$, where $F$ is limit preserving?

Comment: What's the kernel of $B\to C$ ?

Comment: I understand the point about kernels, but how does it preserve the image of $A\to B$?

Comment: The image of $A\to B$ is $A\to B$ because it's a monomorphism: monomorphisms are preserved under limit preserving functors

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314626/reconciling-different-definitions-of-left-exact-functor

Comment: Oh, I am very sorry , I get it now, since $F(A) \to F(B)$ is a monomorphism, the image would be $F(A)$. Thank you for your trouble.